# Create a model and compile it to extract embeddings from an image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to migrate this code [3.3 Omniglot Character set classification using Prototypical Network.ipynb](https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-With-Python/blob/master/03.%20Prototypical%20Networks%20and%20its%20Variants/3.3%20Omniglot%20Character%20set%20classification%20using%20Prototypical%20Network.ipynb), from Tensorflow 1.1 to Tensorflow 2.x.

My doubt is that I don't know what I'm really doing. The code where I have the problem is:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def convolution_block(inputs, out_channels, name='conv'):

    conv = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding='SAME')
    conv = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv, updates_collections=None, decay=0.99, scale=True, center=True)
    conv = tf.nn.relu(conv)
    conv = tf.contrib.layers.max_pool2d(conv, 2)
    
    return conv

def get_embeddings(support_set, h_dim, z_dim, reuse=False):

    net = convolution_block(support_set, h_dim)
    net = convolution_block(net, h_dim)
    net = convolution_block(net, h_dim) 
    net = convolution_block(net, z_dim) 
    net = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(net)
        
    return net
```

And I have migrated to:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D

def get_embedding_function(img_shape):
    inputs = Input(img_shape)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_1')(inputs)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool1')(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_1')(pool1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_1')(pool2)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_1')(pool3)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool4')(conv4)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=pool4)

    model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=(1e-4) * 2), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

This function does not have the same layers than the previous one because I want to test my own network.

**I'm going to use this function to extract features from images**.

I have had to add `model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=pool4)` because if I only return `pool4` it doesn't work. And I have also added `model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=(1e-4) * 2), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])` but **I don't know if I need it.**

Do I need to create the model and compile it to extract features from an image?

Comment: `Do I need to create the model and compile it to extract features from an image?` Maybe. Do you need to train the model, or do you have pretrained weights?

Comment: @Lescurel I will train the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mainly two ways of training a network using the keras API :

- using the `fit` method
- writing a custom loop from scratch.

In both case, if using the `keras` API, you need to create a Model, which is collection of connected layers.

Lets define a simple MLP (multi layer perceptron) Model using keras:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inp = tf.keras.Input((1,))
hidden = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="tanh")(inp)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="simgoid")(hidden)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)
```

Lets also generate some simple synthetic data

```
x = tf.random.normal((100,1))
y = 2*x + 1
```

Note that using a MLP for a regression as simple as this is overkill. A simple linear regression would be enough.

#### Training using `fit`

If you want to use the `fit` method, then you need to compile the model.
Compiling the model is akin to providing the training strategy of the model : which objective function (loss) to use, with which optimization algorithm.

In that case, lets use a simple mean square error as a loss, and a SGD as the optimization algorithm. Once that's done, you can simply call `fit` on your data.

```
>>> model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mse")
>>> model.fit(x,y)
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 4.5469
```

The fit method provides plenty of options, you can explore them by looking at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?hl=en#fit).

#### Writing a training loop from scratch

Sometimes, using the fit method is not flexible enough. In that case, it is possible to train the model from scratch by writing a training loop. In that case, you need to define everything yourself. If  I want to use SDG as an optimizer, and a mean squared error loss function, I can do it that way:

```
opt = tf.optimizers.SGD()
for data,label in zip(x,y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        pred = model(data)
        loss = tf.losses.mse(pred,label)
    grad = tape.gradient([loss], model.weights)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, model.weights))
```

This approach is more flexible, but also more verbose. In that case, I don't need to compile the model. The compiling is only the method that will make the optimizer and the loss function known to fit `method`.

#### Further read

You can read more about :

- training a keras model using `fit` in the [Basic classification: Classify images of clothing](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification) tutorial
- writing a training loop from scratch in the [Writing a training loop from scratch](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/writing_a_training_loop_from_scratch?hl=en) guide.

Answer (score 1):

Compile model or not is depend by the method you use to training the model, i.e:

If you using `model.fit` then you need compile the model before fit the model

If you using [custom training](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough) then you don't have to, just return the model and using it like:

```
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=(1e-4) * 2)
bce = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy()

tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y_pred = model(X)
    loss = bce(y_true, y_pred)

grads = tape.gradient(loss , model.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads , model.trainable_variables))
```